# iOS accessibility method accessibilityPerformMagicTap is not invoked in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, appdelegate, voiceover

I use this code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityPerformMagicTap {
    NSLog(@"Appdelegate = %s",__func__);
    return YES;
}
```

When I click the home button and two-ﬁngered double tap while using VoiceOver activates, this method is not invoked. What is the reason for this? How can I use this method with my music app?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The method is called on the focused accessibility element while the app is foregrounded.

Comment: Spotify had that, How they did

Comment: Spotify is likely responding to [remote control events](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter). Unless otherwise handled by the foregrounded app, the Magic Tap VoiceOver gesture toggles audio playback system-wide.

Comment: thanks, I have another question, when I override accessibilityPerformMagicTap in tableviewController, How can I know which cell the voiceover focused in accessibilityPerformMagicTap method when two-ﬁngered double tap

Comment: Please post a new question on StackOverflow if you need help with a different issue.